# Why is the first character removed when I try to write my own cat function

Tags: c

I want to write the cat command in my own, however, when I come to concatenate two files, some errors come up, its ignoring the first character starts from the second line of the file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *file = NULL;
    char str[1000];
    char line[4096]; //buffer
    int cur_file = argc > 1 ? 1 : 0;

    while (cur_file < argc) {
        if (argc > 1 && *argv[1] != '-') {
            file = fopen(argv[cur_file], "r");
            if (file == NULL) {
                printf("%s : no such file or directory\n", argv[cur_file]);
                exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
            printf("%s\n", str);
            return 0;
        } 
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
          
            char c;
            if((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
                printf("%s", line);
            } else {
                printf("%s\n", line);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
        cur_file++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have a b.txt

```
Hello world!
Great, one more file.
Just what we need.
```

the output is below when i try to run `cat b.txt b.txt`

```
Hello world!
reat, one more file.
ust what we need.
Hello world!
reat, one more file.
ust what we need.
```

also I tried this below,

```
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        int len = strlen(line); 
        line[len - 1] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", line);
  }
```

the output ignore the last character in the last line

I have a b.txt

```
Hello world!
Great, one more file.
Just what we need.
```

the output is below when i try to run cat b.txt b.txt

```
Hello world!
Great, one more file.
Just what we need
Hello world!
Great, one more file.
Just what we need
```

Comment: please do not spam lanuage tags. This looks like C

Comment: Aside: `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: Your code reads a line using `fgets()`, then reads a character using `fgetc()`.   That means, for every successful call of `fgets()` one more character in your file is discarded.    At a quick look, you're trying to handle newline characters in the input file(s).   Problem is, `fgets()` doesn't discard newlines, and doesn't leave one unread - but your approach assumes it does.

Comment: I personally wouldn't care for reading entire lines anyway – just read as many bytes as fit in the buffer, no matter which ones these are, and print out the same amount again. So you might rather want to base your algorithm on `fread` and `fwrite` functions.

Comment: @Zhunan Shuai, Who or what text suggested an `s` in `"%[^\n]s"`?

Answer (score 0):

This code is pointless and wrong:

```
 while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    char c;
    if((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        printf("%s", line);
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
 }
```

In `if ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {` you actually read a character and then you throw it away, IOW you never output this character, and therefore characters are missing from the output.

And also `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a char.

You simply want this:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    printf("%s", line);      
}
```

Keep is simple.

I didn't check the parts with `scanf` though, there may be problems there too.

---

That being said, be aware that your code will only work with text files. As suggested by a comment, you might take a whole different approach by reading the files bytewise with `fread` and `fwrite`.